# Why an empty Array type-converts to zero? +[]

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

just when I thought I understood something about type conversion in JavaScript, I stumbled with this:

```
+[]; // 0
Number([]); // 0
```

My first thought was that I should get NaN, just like if I try to convert an empty object to number:

```
+{}; // NaN
Number({}); // NaN
```

I have been searching about this for a while without any success...

Can somebody explain me why it gets converted to 0 and not to NaN?

Is this behavior standard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In a brief, there are two key points:

- The `toString` method of an empty array returns an empty string.
- An empty string *coerces* to zero using the [unary plus operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) or the [`Number` constructor called as a function](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.7.1) (e.g. `+"" === 0;`).

For example, we can use an object that defines a `toString` method, and returns an empty string to have an equivalent result:

```
var obj = { toString: function () { return "";} };
+obj; //  0
Number(obj); // 0
```

This behavior is completely standard.

Now the long answer:

Both, the [unary plus operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) and the [`Number` constructor called as a function](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.7.1) internally use the [`ToNumber`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.3) abstract operation.

`ToNumber` will use two more internal operations, [`ToPrimitive`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.1) and [`[[DefaultValue]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.1).

When the `ToNumber` operation is applied to an Object, such the empty array in your example, it calls the `ToPrimitive` operation, to get a representative primitive value and call `ToNumber` again using that value <sup>[1]</sup>.

The `ToPrimitive` operation receive two arguments, a Value (which is your array object), and a hint type, which in this case is "Number" since we want to make numeric conversion.

`ToPrimitive` calls the `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method, also with a "Number" hint type.

Now, since the hint type we are using "Number", the `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method now will try to invoke first the `valueOf` method on the object.

Array objects don't have a specific `valueOf` method, the method is the one inherited from [`Object.prototype.valueOf`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.4), and this method simply returns a reference to the *object* itself.

Since the `valueOf` method didn't result in a *primitive value*, now the `toString` method is invoked, and it produces an empty string (which is a primitive value), then the `ToNumber` operation will try to do String-Number conversion and it finally end up with `0`  <sup>[1]</sup>.

But now you might wonder, why an empty string coerces to zero?

```
+""; // 0
```

There is a complete grammar that is used when the [`ToNumber` internal operation is applied to a String type](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.3.1), the `StringNumericLiteral` production.

It has some differences between a NumericLiteral, and one of those differences is that:

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

Comment: +1 Array is actually an object type in JavaScript, so it has a toString() method.

Comment: Why Array objects doesn't have a valueOf method?