# How does the following piece of expression evaluates to "10"

Tags: javascript, expression

I have recently seen an expression from a source, which looks something like below -

```
++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]
```

Entering this into the Chrome (Windows 7, Version 27.0.1453.94 m) console shows a result of `"10"`.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhuKF/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is fairly flexible about converting between data types. The first thing to notice is that `+[]` evaluates to 0.<sup>*</sup> That lets us rewrite the expression as:

```
++[[]][0] + [0]
```

The next thing to notice is that `++[[]][0]` is the preincrement operator applied to the first element of `[[]]`. Normally you can't apply `++` to an array, but JavaScript kindly converts the first element to `0`, so the result is that `++[[]][0]` evaluates to `1` (the first element of `[[]]` having now been incremented). It is kind of like this:

```
var a = [[]];
var b = ++a[0];
// now a will be [1] and b will be 1
```

That leaves us with:

```
1 + [0]
```

JavaScript now converts the int and the array to strings (since `[0]` is not a numeric value) and concatenates them together. Done!

<sup>*</sup> My understanding of how `+[]` becomes `0` is that it is a two-step process: first, `[]` is converted to a string primitive, which is the empty string. The empty string then converts to a number, which is zero. Via the same route, `[1]` evaluates to `'1'` and then to `1`, `[2]` evaluates to `2`, etc. However, `[1, 2]` evaluates to `'1,2'` which evaluates to `NaN`. (The last because the decimal point separator is `.`, not `,`. I don't know what would happen if my locale were different.)

Comment: I pretty much assumed this far. Just wondering about converting `[[]][0]` to `0` part. Which conversion rule is followed during this process?

Comment: @SayemAhmed - While the `++` cannot be applied to an array, it can be applied to an array element. The first element of `[[]]` is `[]`; trying to apply `++` to that triggers JS to convert `[]` to 0 (just like it did with `+[]`).

Comment: Okay, I see your point. I am just finding the behavior of the ++ operator a little difficult to understand. You cannot apply it to array, that I get. But when you apply it to an array element and if the element is itself an array, then it gets converted to a primitive? Does the ECMA specification list this behavior somewhere?

Comment: @SayemAhmed - §11.4.4 says that `++Expr` starts (after some error checking) by evaluating `ToNumber(GetValue(Expr))`. §9.3 specifies that `ToNumber` for an object argument starts by evaluating `ToPrimitive(value, Number)`. That, in turn, (per §9.1) calls the object's `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method. §8.12.8 describes how `[[DefaultValue]]` works for an object when the hint type is Number. The process specified there is essentially what I described: convert to a string (after first unsuccessfully trying to covert to a primitive using `valueOf()`) That's then parsed as a number (per §9.3).

Answer (score 2):

This expression stringifies valid Javascript constructs that yelds `NaN`, numbers, boolean `undefined` etc.

e.g.

```
+[] -> 0  //The unary plus operator is applied to the result of toString applied to an empty array (which is an empty string)

!+[] -> true
```

You can have a look also at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306453/why-an-empty-array-type-converts-to-zero),
and at the [no alnum cheat sheets](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33349).

Comment: I figured out that part. I reduced the expression down to `++[[]][0]+[0]`, just can't figure out how the `1` is coming up here......

Comment: Okay, I see the cheat sheet has listed `++[[]][+[]]` as equivalent to `1`, but doesn't give any explanation........

Answer (score 2):

`+[]` is a number conversion from array to number which is 0.

and `+[0]` is also 0.

So the final result can be deduced  to `(++0) + [0]` which is `1+[0]`.

And for a number adding an array. They are converted to string so the result is actually '10'.

You can log `typeof(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]])` to verify.