# Short-circuiting an empty array in JS has an unexpected outcome: `[] || true == []`

Tags: javascript

In my code I assumed the following `||` short-circuiting was safe:

```
var $holidayExpandBarOrOpeningHours = 
                $(".expandBar + .holidayHours_c").prev() || $(".openingHours");
```

But to my surprise if we short-circuit an empty array with a true statement an empty array is still returned. I will demonstrate with some console code below and my question is why `[] || true` evaluates to `[]`.

```
false || "expected"
"expected"
false == []
true
[] || "expected"
[]
typeof([])
"object"
({}) || "expected"
Object {}
({}) == false
false
{} == false
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
```

Part of me thinks that it is because an array is an `object` which evaluates to true, however if that was the case than based on `({}) == true` one would expect `[] == true`.

Last thing I would like to note is the outcome is the same when using `use 'strict'` mode.

Comment: An empty array is not falsy

Comment: In support of what @rgthree said, [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) article has a simple write-up about truthy/falsy values that you may be interested in.

Comment: `({}) == true` is false, just as `[] == true` is false. The process is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `||` and use `==` *different* rules for the conversion.

The logical-or uses [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) while the equality equals uses [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)/`ToPrimitive`.

---

From [11.11 Binary Logical Operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11):

> 3) If *ToBoolean(lval)* is true, return lval.

Since `ToBoolean([])` is true, `[] || x` results in `[]`. This is also why `if([]) { /* this runs */ }`: arrays in JavaScript are ["truthy" values](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

From [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> 7) If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == *ToNumber(y)*.
>
> 9) [..then] If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison *ToPrimitive(x)* == y.
>
> 5) [..then] If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
>   return the result of the comparison *ToNumber(x)* == y.

The logic applied to `[] == true` is `ToNumber(ToPrimitive([])) == ToNumber(true)`.

---

And the conversion values:

- `ToBoolean([])` is true
- `ToNumber(true)` is 1
- `ToPrimitive([])` is an *empty* string (from `DefaultValue/toString`)

So:

```
ToNumber(ToPrimitive([])) == ToNumber(true)
ToNumber("") == 1
0 == 1
false
```

(Which is a long way to say what John Kugelman said.)

---

Also, `({}) == true` is normally *false* and follows the same conversions as above.

Under a default environment, `ToPrimtive({})` returns a non-empty string (i.e. `"[object Object]"` as per [Object.prototype.toString](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2)). This string will evaluate to NaN after `ToNumber` such that `NaN == 1`; or false.

See [Why an empty Array type-converts to zero? +[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306453/why-an-empty-array-type-converts-to-zero) for more details on the ToPrimitive conversion.

Answer (score 6):

When converted to a boolean value, `[]` is true.

```
> !![]
true
> ![]
false
```

When converted to a number, `[]` is 0. That's why comparing it with false returns true: when comparing two values of different types, JavaScript first converts both to numbers and then compares the numbers.

```
> +[]
0
> +false
0
> +[] == +false
true
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time tracking down *why* the array (`x`) is converted to a number in the `==`. As far as I can tell that will be the result of `ToPrimitive([]) == ToNumber(true)` [via rule 7, then 9, of `==`] - so then `ToPrimitive([]) == 0` (possibly by another pass)? But I can't back that up.

Comment: @user2864740 ToPrimitive(`[]`) yields the empty string, *then* step 5 kicks in (x is string, y is number), and the empty sting is converted to `0`, via ToNumber. (Step 5 because: the boolean turned to a number in step 7 and the array turned to a string in step 9.)

Answer (score 3):

An empty array is an object; objects coerced to booleans are `true`. So

```
({}) || true; // -> {}
[] || true; // -> []
"" || true; // -> true (empty strings are coerced to false)
```

Sidenote - the parentheses around `{}` are required to avoid parsing it as a block.

Comment: Thank you for the response; yes I considered that but see my question again since `[] == false` does not equal `({}) == false`.

Comment: See @JohnKugelman's answer - `==` coerces to `Number`, not `Boolean`. Yes, Javascript is a bit crazy in this respect.