# Is there any order of preference for type conversion?

Tags: javascript

Knowing that javascript automatically converts types when required say example "8" * "3" = 24; but while comparing two different types of js, what type to they convert first.

Let me show you an example.

[image]

here when string "true" is compared with boolean true, then one of them has to convert to other type. what is the preferance here, will the "true" string convert to boolean true which returns a boolean object, or the boolean true converts to "true" string.

in the above i guess the true string is converted to boolean true which is object making the statement false, so why this why not the reverse is there a preferance in type conversion ?

Comment: Yes. There is. This has been answer very many times before. Basically it comes down to: **== is its own magic**. I've discussed it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668845/short-circuiting-an-empty-array-in-js-has-an-unexpected-outcome-true/20668885#20668885 (from a slightly different question angle, which is why it's not a duplicate; in any case, refer to the linked reference)

Comment: You may want to see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: @JamesBlack That documentation actually doesn't cover this case, because "true" *is* a truth-y value (that is, `[ToBoolean("true")]` is `true`), yet the expression with the `"true" == true` is false. [The `==` operator *favors* `[ToNumber]` conversions](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3), which differ from `[ToBoolean]`.

Comment: i am really confused, on what basis the above question is converted string to boolean where there is a reverse chance. I am seeing all the  docs you mentioned but could not find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3).

Basically it comes down to: **== is its own magic**; if anything, it *favors* the [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) conversion. This conversion is a *result* of the equality operator evaluating.

```
"true" == true
"true" == 1      // by rule #7   - ToNumber(true)
0 == 1           // by rule #5   - ToNumber("true")
false            // by rule #1c
```

The [ToBoolean](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) operation is simply *not used* in this case, although it is in other cases where truthiness matters - such as with the logical boolean operators or conditional expressions.

Comment: i think, its not actually ToBoolean its just Boolean(String); explicit conversion

Comment: new Boolean(string); return a boolean object thats correct but just Boolean(string); return true or false on truthy and falsy. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @user3242837 Ah, cool, I did not know that - very neat. (However, I still mean the `ToBoolean` internal operation in my reply :)