# Assigning `{} + []` to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

> ```
> >> {} + []
> 0
> ```

So EmptyObject + EmptyArray evaluates to `0`. (Disclaimer: I don't fully understand why this is.) Okay, now I want to assign this `0` to a variable! Seems pretty easy:

> ```
> >> var a = {} + [];
> undefined
> >> a
> "[object Object]"
> ```

Well, maybe not so easy. *Googles a bit...* Aha! `{}` in this context [is actually a code block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930789/2846923), not an empty object. So lemme make it look more like a code block:

> ```
> >> var a = 
>    {
>
>    }
>    + [];
> undefined
> >> a
> "[object Object]"
> ```

...dang. *Note to self: JavaScript ignores whitespace.*

---

Is there any way I can assign `{} + []` (or similar) to a variable, but still have that `{} + []` evaluate to `0`?

Comment: Why would you want to? XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because it would be funny. :P Do I have to have a better reason?

Comment: `{}` after `=` gets interpreted differently.

Comment: This reminds me of this gem: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @SergeyK That's actually where I first heard about `{} + [] = 0`

Comment: @KevinB That's what I figured, given what the linked answer said.

Comment: This may help: http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an empty Array type-converts to zero? +\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306453/why-an-empty-array-type-converts-to-zero)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no way to assign that exact code to a variable and have it work out to 0, because the parsing of that code that gives 0 does not constitute an expression†, and only expressions can be assigned. The reason you're getting that 0 is because the braces are being essentially ignored as an empty statement and then you're getting the result of the expression `+ []` (that is, the unary + operator applied to an empty array). So in order to get the same result out, you'd need to alter the expression so that it just worked out to `+[]`. For example, you could do `var a = ({}, + [])` and that would give you the right answer (because the comma causes `+ []` to be evaluated separately).

† This is also the reason it gives a different answer when you try to assign it. That forces the code to be parsed as an expression, so the `{}` is no longer an empty block and the `+` is no longer the unary +, but instead it's the binary plus with an empty object and an empty array as operands.

Comment: i bow before you o' great God of Javascript!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var a = eval("{} + []");

console.log(a); // returns (integer) 0
```

Though `eval` method isn't recommended to use

Comment: *How* isn't the most important here, I think, but *why* is.

Comment: maybe the length of {} + the length of [] which is 0 since both are empty

Comment: @Huangism Nope, it is not calculated with length because if we'd have `[2]` for instance the result will be `2`

Comment: @ToKeN yea but [2] + 2 results in 22 and not 4, so [2] must of been a string

Comment: @Huangism No, `eval("{} + [2] + 2");` gives `4`

Comment: @Huangism Yes, without `eval` it gather result as a `string`

Comment: Even without `eval`, `{} + [2] + 2` gives `4`.  That's because it's treated as `+[2] + 2`, and `+[2]` evaluates to `2`.  However, `[2] + 2` is different, this gives `22` because in that case `[2]` is treated as `"2"`.