# Why +[] or +"" equal to 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know in javascript, `Array` does not support `+` operation, so `+[]` would be convert to `+ [].toString()`, but I can't figure out why `+""` is equal to zero.

Comment: I think this is a unary operator.

Comment: It converts to zero because there is a specific rule in the ECMAScript spec that requires an empty string to be converted that way when performing numeric conversion.

Comment: The sequence in the ECMA spec is painful to follow and copy here (see https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2016/#sec-tonumber especially), can't we find one of the many identical questions ?

Comment: `+[]` result is `0` and does not equal `[].toString()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `+[]` is equal to `+ [].toString()`

Comment: @MarkoCen I just tried it in my console... Why would it be anything else? The plus unary operator tries to cast to a number. An empty array will be 0.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: the algorithm used to convert an array to a number performs a `toString()` operation. Do this experiment: `x = []; x.toString = function() { return "123" }; console.log(+x);`

Comment: @squint ah. That makes sense

Comment: A related question: [All falsey values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript). The harsh response to this question is surprising ... especially given the enlightening comments that it has produced.

Comment: Here's a more direct [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306453/why-an-empty-array-type-converts-to-zero). I don't think this was that bad of a question, but it has been asked several times in many different forms, so that may explain the votes.

Answer (score -1):

Because **empty string** `("")` is `false` in javascript *(As Javascript is a dialect of ECMAScript, and ECMAScript language specification clearly defines this behavior)* and `+` **unary operator** converts `false` to `0`.

**Reference**: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @evolutionxbox check now..

Comment: It isn't because an empty string is false *(I assume you mean "falsey")*. There are other falsey values that are not converted to zero.

Comment: To be pedantic, `""` is falsey (not strictly false), so a coercion to boolean comes first, then boolean to number.

Comment: @squint All false, 0, empty strings '' and "", NaN, undefined, and null are always evaluated as false; everything else is true.

Comment: @void: They're "falsey", not `false`, which is a distinct value, but that doesn't have anything to do with how it's converted to a number. If they were always evaluated as `false`, then `"" == null` would be `true`.

Comment: This is just incorrect. This has _nothing_ to do with booleans or falsyness. The actual algorithm is [`ToNumber` with a string argument](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type): _“A_ StringNumericLiteral _that is empty or contains only white space is converted to `+0`.”_.